# Get the div inside a th inside the thead of a table css

Tags: html, css

I know that I can get the `thead` element inside a `table` with css like this:

```
table thead
```

but how would I go about getting the div inside a th element inside the thead of a table? Can I get this in one short css expression like this:

```
table thead th div
```

Or would I have to use classes and stuff

Thank you

Comment: Well a div inside a th isn't correct XHTML, however it will still be possible.  You can give the div an id, and reference it along the lines of: table thead th div#myid { }

Comment: You can do it exactly how you have written it. Did you try it?

Comment: Also, as long as it isn't ambiguous, you can shorten it to `th div` or `table div`, etc.

Comment: @Alias who said anything about XHTML?

Comment: @cimmanon It's called information, incase he/she doesn't know, is that okay?

Comment: @Alias Information is fine, except for the part where it is irrelevant.  No version of XHTML is a recommendation.  "HTML5 is intended to subsume not only HTML 4, but also XHTML 1 and DOM Level 2 HTML." ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can I get this in one short css expression like this?*

[Yes, that works](http://jsfiddle.net/pY3yW/)

*Or would I have to use classes and stuff*

No, you don't need to use classes in this situation (see above JsFiddle).

*Should you use classes and stuff?*

Eh, when it *really* comes down to it you're fine so long as your selectors target exactly what you want. But there is the notion of *css efficiency* that [might be worth reading about](http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/) if you're just learning about selectors.

*Note:* The first comment says that this isn't valid XHTML, but it's fine if you're using Html5 ([which you should be!](http://diveintohtml5.info/introduction.html)). The [current Html5 specs](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) tell us that a `div` is expected wherever flow content is expected, and a `th` expects flow content with a few explicit restrictions – [but divs aren't one of them.](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html#the-th-element)

Further supporting this is the fact that this little bit of code [validates as Html5](http://validator.w3.org/check):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><div>hello</div></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First comment says it isn't valid XHTML (X!)

Comment: @user2019515, yes, yes, look at that! I edited my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can use:

```
table thead th div
```

But shorter would be:

```
table div
```

Which selects all divs in the table or if you only wants the divs in the thead:

```
thead div
```